# Key "ProxyOverride" in Windows registry - is it limited to 256 characters?

Tags: proxy, windows-registry, blocking

In general, is there such a thing that Windows registry keys with string-values should be no more than 256 characters long? In particular, I wonder if the string-value below should be subject to such limit. This specific key is found in `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings`.

[image]

---

I use a tool that hosts its own proxy server on Windows to block certain sites on-demand. The addresses in `ProxyOverride` are used to let go connections that shouldn't have been blocked in the first place (for example, OneNote won't sync without sufficient entries in the ProxyOverride list). From time to time (over many years), the desktop client of the tool may wipe out the contents in `ProxyOverride`. Today, I was told the following:

> We researched this and we believe that Microsoft Windows actually has a 256 character limitation in the proxy settings, and because your settings are more than 256, Windows is erasing them. You could probably experiment with removing some of the Windows domains, which could help make the list shorter,  ...

What confused me the most is that - if there were such a 256 characters limit, why my ultra-long settings stay in some Windows 10 machines but not others? And, why such setting may stay for weeks, and should go away when the blocker-tool update itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit of 255 characters was lifted since more than a decade ago.

The tool is falsely truncating the value - probably by some old code that
just stayed inside the tool.

I suggest issuing a bug report to the developers of this tool.
If you could specify the tool that you use,
we could perhaps find more info.

Comment: Appreciate your definitive comment falsifying the bold claim from the developers of "the tool". I will forward your advice to them, to see if they can actually get the issue resolved. (Well, I've paid for a "lifetime subscription" of the tool, and the issue with proxy settings has been bothering me since 2018 or so. Will submit another bug report again.)